# Akka Http.get(ActorSystem) leads to Ambiguous method call in intellij

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, akka, akka-http

intellij has problems with when a subclass specifies a more specific return type. This is the case for Akka's Http.get(ActorSystem) method. This is issue is reported to JB but they have not responded yet.

[SCL-12302](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-12302)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a simple solution for the problem. Simply install the Scala plugin from JetBrains:

File -> Settings... -> Plugins -> Install JetBrains plugin... -> search for Scala.

After restarting the IDE the failure is gone.

Comment: FYI: after installing the scala plugin, the compilation process slows down significantly. it takes 5-6 seconds for almost everything.

Comment: @YeshodhanKulkarni , hmm I am not facing the problem you mentioned. Everything is as fast as before. Nevertheless you should raise your issue at the intellij plugin tracker

Comment: This does get rid of the inspection error for me but it still fails to compile with the same ambiguous method error in Intellij CE. From the Scala plugin's info section : "Support for Play Framework, Akka and Scala.js is enabled only with IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate." Maybe that's why.